# Finding Tangent Planes to Paraboloid Containing a Specified Line

Tags: calculus

Find all tangent planes to the paraboloid $z = 100 - x^2 - y^2$ that contain the line $[x,y,z] = [10,5,40] + t[3,-1,-4]$.

I have looked around and have not been able to find a clear response for solving this type of problem.

Comment: Hmmm... LaTeX formatting would make this *much* more readable. Similarly, no matter the lack of a solution.. what have *you* tried and where do *you* get stuck?

Comment: I am new to this site and am just learning the different formatting.. sorry about that. I get stuck at where to even start because I do not know how to find the normal to the planes that would be tangent.

Comment: can you find tangent lines to the level curves at the point of interest?

Comment: I honestly do not know how. To find the tangent planes i will need the normal vector to the plane. I am confused about how the line is incorporated and how to find where on the paraboloid the tangent planes contain the line.

Comment: How about something basic: can you find *any* tangent plane to the surface (other than the obvious one at $(0,0,100)$, that is)?

Answer (score 0):

$$z=f(x,y)=100-x^2-y^2$$
$$f_x(x,y)=-2x$$
$$f_y(x,y)=-2y$$

Tangent plane formula at point $P(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is

$$z-z_0=f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$

$$z-z_0=-2x_0(x-x_0)-2y_0(y-y_0)$$

$$z=-2x_0x-2y_0y+2(x_0^2+y_0^2)+z_0$$

$$z=-2x_0x-2y_0y+100+(x_0^2+y_0^2)$$

This tangent plane must contain $(10,5,4)$,

Hence $$4=-20x_0-10y_0+100+(x_0^2+y_0^2)$$

Also, let's find another point on the line, say $(10,5,4)+(3,-1,4)=(13,4,8)$

$$8=-26x_0-8y_0+100+(x_0^2+y_0^2)$$

Your task now is to recover $x_0$ and $y_0$ to recover the tangent plane $z=-2x_0x-2y_0y+100+(x_0^2+y_0^2)$

Answer (score 0):

$z = 100 - x^2 - y^2$ that contain the line $[x,y,z] = [10,5,40] + t[3,-1,-4]$.

The parametric equations of the line are $r:(10+3t,5-t,40-4t)$.

The points $A(10,5,40)$ and $B(13,4,36)$ lie on $r$

The plane tangent to the paraboloid $z=f(x,y)=100-x^2-y^2$ in the point $(a,b)$ has equation
$$z-f(a,b)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)(x-a)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)(y-b)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-2x;\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-2y$$
is in this case we have
$$\pi:z-(100-a^2-b^2)=-2a(x-a)-2b(y-b)$$
Conditions

$A\in\pi$ and $B\in\pi$
$$
\begin{cases}
a^2+b^2-60=-2 (10-a) a-2 (5-b) b\\
a^2+b^2-64=-2 (13-a) a-2 (4-b) b \\
\end{cases}
$$
subtract the two equations
$ b=3a-2$ and substitute in the first
$$a^2+(3 a-2)^2-60=-2 (10-a) a-2 (7-3 a) (3 a-2)\to 5 a^2-31 a+42=0$$
Solutions are $a=2;\;b=4$ and $a=\frac{21}{5};\;b=\frac{11}{5}$

So we have two tangent planes
$$\pi_1:z=-4 x-8 y+120;\;\pi_2:z=-\frac{42 x}{5}-\frac{22 y}{5}+\frac{3062}{25}$$